# Need to Skip Repetitive logs in Elixir

Tags: logging, erlang-otp, elixir

I have a particular log statement in my Elixir code which is supposed to be called very frequently, but I dont want to print that log statement every time. May be I want to print that once in every 5 times.

Please help if there is a way to do this. It is flooding my log file way too quickly! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

There is no simple / standard way of doing that in general. By if you really need to handle just this specific case, and you want to log this statement "from time to time", the simplest solution would be the following:

```
Enum.random(0..4) > 0 || Logger.info("My message")
```

This code should trigger log message in 20% of cases.

Please note however, that this will not be the same as "exactly once every 5 times" and this will require to generate random number each time log is being triggered. Whether generation of random number is "heavier" then actual log operation (or even relevant at all) depends heavily on specific environment / situation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any packages that already do this but you could implement your own throttling with something like this:

```
def maybe_log(msg, 0, log_every) do
  Logger.info(msg)
  log_every
end
def maybe_log(_msg, n, log_every) when n < 0, do: log_every
def maybe_log(_msg, n, _), do: n-1

# usage
log_count = maybe_log(msg, log_count, log_every)
```